# Obtaining Facebook graph api data for user generated posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping, facebook-insights

I am having some trouble determining how to go about a certain issue. I am pretty new at trying to obtain social media data. Say an internet user publishes something that is essentially a post from from a website that is external to Facebook, to the user's Facebook feed. Is there a way to obtain the amount of likes, shares, comments, and other insight type data from those posts? I'm aware/currently learning about Facebook's open graph api, but I am unsure if it allows for this type of query. It seemed to be primarily for people, pages, and places, and I have not found a way to query only posts from a website specifically.
                                                                                   To be more detailed, a user will have the option of posting a jpeg type image to their Facebook feed. This is for a single website, where the website would like to do this in order to gauge how those posts are being perceived and interacted with by other Facebook users. Is there a way to obtain data on these specifically?

Also, if so, is there a way to tag or apply specific identifications to categories of these posts in some way before they are posted by the user to their feed, to allow for segmentation of the data?  Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You won’t be able to read any user’s post on their own wall, unless the user explicitly grants your app permission to do so. (And that again likely won’t be approved by Facebook in review, because they want you to use permissions to directly increase the user experience, and not just for analytical purposes.) Maybe you should rather look into Domain Insights, those might be a better way to gain such data.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure what Facebook would and would not allow. Is this true of obtaining information regarding the edges(likes, reacts, etc.) connected to a post as well? I will definitely look into the domain insights. Thanks.